# Telebot - Создание клавиатуры с названием + смайл, а отправка сообщения без смайла

Tags: python, telebot

Можно ли создать клавиатуру в библиотеке telebot где название "клавиши" будет "❔Помощь", а при нажатии отправляется текст без смайлика = помощь

```
def start_menu():
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3, resize_keyboard=True)
    reg = types.KeyboardButton(text="регистрация")
    com = types.KeyboardButton(text="❕команды")
    helpi = types.KeyboardButton(text="❔помощь")
    keyboard.add(reg, com, helpi)
return keyboard
```

Я только недавно начал изучать эту библиотеку, буду рад вашей помоще и советам.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton, в них можно писать любой текст и прописывать любые действия без отправки сообщений вообще. А кнопки клавиатуры, которые Вы используете, потому и называются кнопками клавиатуры, что они фактически заменяют ручной ввод, так что отправлено всегда будет ровно то, что написано в них

Также рекомендую использовать библиотеку aiogram, асинхронность - это хорошо.